# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not working in live site

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, view, uri

I have a popup window for change password in my codeigniter site. I can open this window from any page. So after change password completed, it will redirect to the same page. To redirect, I'm  using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I set this in hidden field and send to the server in form submit. 
Here is my code:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="modalclose" data-dismiss="modal"></span>
    <h2 class="head edit">Change Password</h2>          
    <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Home/changePassword" method="post">
        <div class="field-wrap">                
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter current Password" name="changePasswordCurrent" id="changePasswordCurrent" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="changePasswordCurrentError" class="validation-cls rt"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">                
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter new Password" name="changePasswordNew" id="changePasswordNew" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="changePasswordNewError" class="validation-cls rt"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">                
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="changePasswordConfirm" id="changePasswordConfirm" autocomplete="off">
            <span id="changePasswordConfirmError" class="validation-cls rt"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">     
            <input type="hidden" name="requestURI" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
            <button class="fill" id="saveNewPassword" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Controller: **Home.php**

```
public function changePassword() {
    if($this->session->userdata('UserID') != ''){
        $data = $this->input->post();  
        $result = $this->Home_model->changePassword($data);
        redirect($data['requestURI']);
    }
    else {
        redirect('../');
    }        
}
```

this code is working in my local server, but not in live site.
First attempt to change password is working, but it adds `index.php` to the url as `http://example.com/index.php`
So if I tried to change password again, the redirection will not work because it adds `index.php` again to the url like `http://example.com/index.php/index.php`
This issue exists only in live site.

Comment: Try `redirect(base_url($data['requestURI']));`

Comment: Can you print_r($_SERVER)  see if there is REQUEST_URI in your live site.

Comment: @Aggarat ,I cannot test this now because its already live

Comment: @Yahiya I cannot test this now with live site. But it is not working in local server, Its repeating project name ex. `http://myip:8080/SMS/approve-cost` changed to `http://myip:8080/SMS/SMS/approve-cost#`

Comment: @geeth of course you can test it on a live site. Just make a new file - call it test.php - in it var_dump($_SERVER); and call it directly - domainname.com/test.php and see the results. When you are done - delete the file

Answer (score 0):

First load the url helper( if it not loaded)

```
$this->load->helper('url');
 $currentURL = current_url(); //http://example.com/controller
```

pass `$currentUrl` from your controller.
If you have any query string.
find out the query string

```
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //my_id=1,3

$fullURL = $currentURL . '?' . $params; 

echo $fullURL;   //http://myhost/main?my_id=1,3
```